# How functions arguments of model automatically populated

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-api

hello all just now i create

1. getinfo($id=null){ return $xyz; } function in model
2. calling above function using $this->xyz=$this->get('info'); in view.html.php file so will be used by info layout
3. now info layout will called as 'index.php?option=com_student&view=student&layout=info&id=3'

> now when i call the info layout using above url the id argument of getinfo method in model automatically populated with the id i supplied in url how joomla doing this

i think there is something that I'm missing

Comment: Please provide the full source code of your model class

Comment: sir above is done by joomla default getinfo is the only function that i described here

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, main controller of application remember arguments for subcontrollers, so model get same Params from controller. Documentation get answers too ☺ https://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview

Regards